# What is the use of accumulator in c++ boost library?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, time-complexity

I've just read the guide of boost library in c++. And I didn't understand the part of accumulator.

In the guide it said every accumulator can own its features, such as tag::min or tag::mean. And you can use the min function(macro) if you own these features.

So why can't I just use vector in STL and use algorithms like min_element(v.begin(), v.end())? What is the advantage of using accumulator?

Also the guide had written the words
"Accumulator Complexity O(1) 
Extractor Complexity O(1)".
What does that mean? Is it related on time complexity? Is this the advantage of accumulator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a vector, you have to store every single value. This takes memory, but for the tasks an accumulator is intended for, there is no actual need to store those values — for some calculations, you only need to update some small amount of state when a new value is given.

You could just write a space-efficient algorithm to perform the calculation without all that storage, or you could use the accumulators which have done that work for you.

Furthermore, the accumulators library provides some statistical tools that the standard library does not.

And, yes, *O(1)* means "constant time complexity", which tells us another serious benefit of this approach — its performance does not get worse as the quantity of numbers gets bigger.

[Here's a more in-depth explanation](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.accumulators).